# I am trying to read data from firebase while the user is typing, but I get this error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeed614ff8)

Tags: swift, firebase, uisearchbar

I am trying to fetch data from firebase while the user is typing and I want to display that data in a tableview, but when I run my code I get this error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeed614ff8)

This is how the structure of my database looks like.

- users

  - uid

    - email
    - emailNotifications
    - username
    - fullName

This is what my code looks like. Instead of searching via the searchbar I just entered my own value(There is a user who has the username ginger) for this test.

```
//MARK: - Tableview Datasource Methods

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return findFriends(text: "gin").count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addFriendCell", for: indexPath) as! AddFriendTableViewCell

        cell.lblName?.text =  findFriends(text: "gin")[indexPath.row].name

        cell.lbluserName?.text = findFriends(text: "gin")[indexPath.row].username




        return cell
    }

    func findFriends(text: String) -> [User] {


        let user = User()
        var userArray = [User]()

        let ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryStarting(atValue: text).queryEnding(atValue: text+"\u{f8ff}").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in


            for userSnapshot in snapshot.children{

                let userSnapshot = userSnapshot as! DataSnapshot
                guard let dictionary = userSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

                user.name = (dictionary["name"] as? String)!
                user.username = (dictionary["username"] as? String)!
                userArray.append(user)
            }

        })
        tableView.reloadData()
        return userArray


}
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: It's also a really bad idea to attempt to load data asynchronously from `cellForRowAt` and it's an even worse idea to call `reloadData` from inside `cellForRowAt`. And why call `findFriends` twice?

Comment: Any exclamation mark can crash the code. By the way: Returning something from `findFriends` won’t work anyway. And there are another few pretty bad practices.

Comment: I don't know. My app suddenly crashes. Then goes to a file called FrepoInfo.m and the displays this line in red: NSString* cachedInternalHost = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:internalHostKey];

Comment: @vadian. I'm pretty new to swift and programming in general. Why won't that work?